# My formula to add 1 year to a date in an adjacent cell works, but not when I populate that adjacent cell with a value from a UserForm in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a UserForm that I've created with a textbox for date entry.  When a user completes this form, this date populates on a sheet in the workbook.  In the adjacent cell, I have a formula that adds 365 days to that date and is formatted to show if the date is occurring soon (60 days out, 30 days out). But, if there's no date in this referenced cell, then the formula adds a year to another date in the next adjacent cell. here's the formula for that date:

```
=IF([@[First Certification Date]],IF(ISNUMBER([@[Date of Last Annual]]),[@[Date of Last Annual]]+365,[@[First Certification Date]]+365),"")
```

Worth mentioning that the information in the user form is also updated on another sheet, with only this date being updated on the sheet in question.

Here's my VBA code:

Sub Submit()

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim trow As Range
Dim annrow As Range
Dim ans As Worksheet
   
    
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NSE Tracker")


    
With sh

    .Range("F13").EntireRow.Insert
    .Range("F13").Value = UserForm.txtDate.Value
    .Range("G13").Value = UserForm.txtName.Value
    .Range("H13").Value = UserForm.txtInitials.Value
    .Range("I13").Value = UserForm.cmbFac.Value
    .Range("J13").Value = UserForm.cmbPos.Value
    .Range("K13").Value = UserForm.cmbType.Value
    .Range("L13").Value = UserForm.txtScore.Value
    .Range("M13").Value = UserForm.txtEvaluator.Value
    .Range("N13").Value = UserForm.txtRem.Value
    .Range("O13").Value = IIf(UserForm.optEvalNo.Value = True, "No", IIf(UserForm.OptEvalNA = True, "N/A", "Yes"))
    .Range("P13").Value = IIf(UserForm.OptNRNo.Value = True, "No", IIf(UserForm.OptNRNA = True, "N/A", "Yes"))
    .Rows.AutoFit

End With

If UserForm.cmbType = "Annual" Then

Set ans = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Facility Annual Tracker")

With ans
    Set annrow = .Range("F:F").Find(What:=UserForm.txtName, LookAt:=xlPart)
                            
    Set trow = Range("I:I").Rows(annrow.Row)

    .Cells(annrow.Row, "I").Value = UserForm.txtDate

                    
    End With
    End If
```

End Sub

Only if the type of evaluation is "annual" will this section of code populate that second sheet with the date.  The code finds the user and updates their line effectively, but the formula in the adjacent cell does not calculate based on it.

One solution I've tried is to change the format of the cell in question to a date format, thinking that maybe it's automatically formatted as "text" from the userform.txtdate entry:

```
    .Range("I:I").NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
```

and what's strange is that it effectively changes the format for all the cells in that range (the other dates of the other users) but NOT the cell that I've just filled with the date.

I'm a beginner with VBA, sorry if my code looks bad!

[Image of date entry on userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGz3R.png)

Comment: You cannot apply `Date` format of a cell containing a string. Even if it looks (for you) as a date... Please, show us how that (probably, string) Date looks and mention which is your system default Date formatting. Mainly which appears first. The Day or the Month?

Comment: So all of the dates in the column that this date is entered into are formatted as mon-yy.  my system default is mm/dd/yyyy I guess?  Maybe I need to change the forms txtDate field to something that's not just a string but a date too?

Comment: But I clearly asked to **show us how that (probably, string) Date looks**. I, or somebody else will be able to suggest you a way of solving after that... Not the format you need, which is irrelevant right now. How exactly the date is displayed in the control where from your code takes it

Comment: Ok, maybe I don't understand your question? Are you asking for a literal picture of what the userform entry looks like?  I added that to the original post.

Comment: Not exactly... Just copy the string as it exists **in the text box where from the code copies it**. I mean, such a string can/must be converted to date **before copying it to a cell**.

Comment: Oh, ok.  It looks like 8/17/2022.  That's what's in the text box and what gets sent to the cell in the worksheet.

Comment: I will post a function able to transform such a string (m/dd/yyyy) in date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use the next function:

```
Function TextToDate(strText As String, sep As String) As Date
   Dim arrD: arrD = Split(strText, sep)
   
   TextToDate = DateSerial(CLng(arrD(2)), CLng(arrD(0)), CLng(arrD(1)))
End Function
```

You can test it using:

```
Sub testTextToD()
   Dim x As String
   x = "8/17/2022"
   Debug.Print TextToDate(x, "/")
End Sub
```

or

```
     .Range("F13").Value = TextToDate(UserForm.txtDate.Value, "/")
```

If `UserForm.txtDate` is the text box where you need copying the string as date...

Comment: Thank you for your solution!  I actually found something that worked and with less trouble.  If I just write:    .Cells(annrow.Row, "I").Value = CDate(UserForm.txtDate)   it works!